# Looking for an ideological word (-ism) to say overgeneralize something

Tags: single-word-requests, philosophy

I am looking for a word, probably ending with -sm/ism but not necessarily that is to say because one attribute of someone or something is bad, then everything about this person or thing is bad. Is there a word to express this philosophical belief?

Comment: sounds a little like "guilt by association"

Comment: Stereotyping may work.

Comment: Could you please explain your question more fully?  You might be speaking of a perfectly arguable point of view.  So:  'It does not matter how good a parent or generous to poor people a drug baron is, s/he is stil a (completely) bad person."  On the other hand, the point might be that just because a person has one fault, even if it is a serious fault, it is wrong to generalise from that and condemn the person's entire character.  Both sides are arguable.

Comment: Please can you supply an example sentence where you would use the word.